# Panel to resize only specified components

Tags: java, swing, layout, resize, panel

I want to create Panel that stores multiple components, but only resizes the ones I want when I resize panel. For example if I have panel that stores 1 label and 2 textfields I want to be able to tell it to resize only textfields and not label size. Does any layout do that already or do I have to start learning to write custom layouts?

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), is your friend, in such needs :-) Here you can specify, `GridBagConstraints.fill` property to define, how you want your component to fill the area on expansion. It can have any value from `BOTH, VERTICAL, HORIZONTAL and NONE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are layout managers available which include that behavior (well, sort of). For example the [`FormLayout` from JGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/) allows to divide your panel in columns and specify the resize behavior of each of the individual columns.

A typical use case is where you have a form-like structure (column 1 containing a label, column 2 an input field) where you want on a resize to only resize the second column, ensuring visibility of the label and letting the input fields use all the extra space that is available.

Comment: or MigLayout (SpringLayout) too +1

Answer (score 0):

By default there is not layout manager that look at the type and then decide to act. You could use different containers to simulate that behavior, but implementing own layout manager would be more clean solution IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly set all sizes of components which you don't want to be resizable to same values.

For example:

```
Jlabel aLabel = new Jlabel("text");
Dimension d = new Dimension(50,20);
aLabel.setPreferredSize(d);
aLabel.setMinimumSize(d);
aLabel.setMaximumSize(d);
```

Comment: I would advise against this solution as you may go against L&F specifics. There are many LayoutManagers where you can indicate that you want the preferred size, not more, not less.

Comment: @Rohit Malish: Well, that's true. I propose first try something. Then ask new question about specific problem you are faced with.

Comment: *"I propose first"* I propose to not give answers that are almost certain to come to later questions on how to fix the problem(s) with the suggested 'fix'.